# How to find directory name of a just downloaded folder

Tags: python, bittorrent, libtorrent, irssi

I use rtorrent on ubuntu that download folder with rar files inside..  And I want to automatically run a script that unrar, maketorrent and other things to that unrarred file.  My question is..  How can i get the dirname of the directory just downloaded? It s always different so I cant use a Variable or something like that.  For now,  i am downloading everything to /X and extract /x/*.rar to /X2.  But its a very ugly way because i have to always delete everything in /X before starting a new download or everything will mess up.

I actually have the name of the directory Which,  using irssi, is stored in a variable $releasename,  but thats another program,   i dont think i can import it to python.. Or maybe Yes, i don't know..

Comment: You could detect the latest download by taking the folder with the newest timestamp in your download folder .. would that work for you?

Comment: Probably not.  If i have two downloads at the same time wouldnt timestamp change?